# ReactJS build internal page url not working

Tags: javascript, reactjs, .htaccess

I just `build` my `reactjs` project with `npm run build` and then upload in my website directory. when I run website for example `website.com` it show homepage, and when you click on links it works good, once you refresh your page only on internal pages, like `website.com/Login` it give me `404` error.

I tried solution with `.htaccess` but nothing changed:

```
RewriteEngine on 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d 
RewriteRule . ./index.html [L]
```

And this is my `package.json`

```
  "name": "homer",
  "homepage": "https://homer.com",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": false,
```

Also I use `react-router`

```
import {Switch, Route, Redirect, BrowserRouter} from 'react-router-dom';

<Route exact path='/Login' component={Login}></Route>
```

I run website on centos vps. How can I solve this issue?